# Explicitly specifying the main package to run tests for in golang with goconvey

Tags: testing, go, goconvey

How do I explicitly say with my go test command to run only tests for the main package and not others in my source directory.

At the moment it's working with `$go test -v`. But... I am using goconvey as well and it seems to be running recursively. According to this page https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/wiki/Profiles I have a file where I can pass arguments into the go test command. I know you can `go test -v ./...` for recursive or `go test -c packagename/...` but how do I just do it for the main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiles is one to accomplish this, but you can also specify a 'depth' for the runner:

```
$ goconvey -depth=0
```

A value of `0` limits the runner to the working directory.

Run `goconvey -help` for details.